# Separation of Hamilton's Principal Function

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism

In Goldstein's "Classical Mechanics", at page 437, a two-dimensional anisotropic harmonic oscillator is studied by means of Hamilton-Jacobi formalism. In particular, Goldstein claims that:

> Since the coordinates and momenta separate into two distinct sets [one set for the $x$-coordinate and one for the $y$-coordinate], the principal function can be written as a sum of the characteristic function for each pair.

I understand why we use the characteristic function (the Hamiltonian does not depend explicitly on time), however I do not see explicitly why would the characteristic function split into two terms, one for each pair.

How does one go about proving this statement rigorously? and what does "the coordinates and momenta split into two distinct sets" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one set with $x$ and $p_x$ plus another set with $y$ and $p_y$.  The physics of course is that the $x$-oscillation is independent of the $y$-oscilation.

Separation is an ansatz, *i.e.* you try a separable form and see where it will take you.  There is no guarantee that the function will always be separable this way (especially as the system may not in general be fully integrable.).

You can’t prove an ansatz. Either you get mileage out of it, or you don’t.